# parameter Intent from onActivityResult receiving null value

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, onactivityresult

I am trying implement the basic example from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). It works fine in the first version, when I had only this 2 methods:

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        // display error state to the user
    }
}
```

and

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

but when I add the methods `private fun createImageFile(): File` and `private fun galleryAddPic()` described in the tutorial, and change the method `dispatchTakePictureIntent` to this:

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    println(ex.stackTrace)
                    null
                }
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "org.kleber.camera.fileprovider", it)
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                        println(e.stackTrace)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
2022-03-15 17:16:40.946 11151-11151/org.kleber.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.kleber.camera, PID: 11151
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {org.kleber.camera/org.kleber.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5579)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5620)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap
        at org.kleber.camera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:66)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8550)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5572)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5620) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
```

Anyone can see what I am possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes. You will not get a -thumbnail- bitmap then.

Comment: what you mean? I want take the picture taken and add to the ImageView in the layout, and in the same time save the image. I think that's what `dispatchTakePictureIntent` should be doing?

Comment: Your app will not save the image but the camera app choosen by the user does.The camera app will not deliver a thumbnail bitmap then.i